# How can i remove disabled attribute from KendoUI dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

How can I remove the `disabled` attribute from the kendo DropdownList input field?

I have input field shown below on button click I would like to enable it. It's disabled by default.

```
<input disabled="disabled" id="PersonStatusID" name="PersonStatusID" style="width: 100%; display: none;" value="5" data-role="dropdownlist" type="text">
```

I tried the following but none of them are working for me.

```
document.getElementById('PersonStatusID').removeAttr('disabled');
$("#PersonStatusID").data("kendoDropDownList").enable(true);
$("#PersonStatusID").prop('disabled',false);
document.getElementById('PersonStatusID').prop('disabled',false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest the following:

```
 var list = $("#PersonStatusID").data("kendoDropDownList");
 list.enable(true);
```

Ref: https://www.telerik.com/forums/disable-enable-and-rebind-the-dropdownlist